# Z3: How to best encode a "switch statement"?

Tags: z3, smt

I want to create an expression that selects one of a given set of expressions. Given an array of expressions

```
Expr[] availableExprs = ...;
```

with statically known length, I want Z3 to select any one of these (like a switch statement). In case the problem is SAT I need a way to find out which of these was selected in the model (its index in the array).

What is the fastest way to encode this?

I considered these approaches so far:

1. Have an **integer** restricted to `[0, arrayLength)` and use ITE to select one of those expressions. The model allows me to extract this integer. Unfortunately, this introduces the integer theory to the model (which previously did not use integers at all).
2. Have **one boolean for each possible choice**. Use ITE to select an expression. Assert that exactly one of those booleans is true. This strategy does not need any special theory (I think) but the encoding might be too verbose.
3. Store the expressions into an **array** expression and read from that array using an integer. This saves the ITE chain but introduces the array theory.

Clearly, all of these work, but they all seem to have drawbacks. What is the best strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to encode is that an element v is in a finite set {e1, ..., en} (with sort U), you can do this using smtlib2 as follows:

```
(declare-fun v () U)
(declare-fun p1 () Bool)
...
(assert (= p1 (= v e1)))
(assert (= p2 (= v e2)))
...
(assert (= pn (= v en)))

(assert (or p1 ... pn))
```

The variable v will be equal to one of the elements in "the array" of {e1 ... en}. And pi must be true if the selection variable v is equal to ei. This is basically a restatement of Nikolaj's suggestion, but recast for arbitrary sorts.

Note that multiple pi may be set to true as there is no guarantee ei != ej. If you need to ensure no two elements are both selected, you will need to figure out what semantics you want. If the {e1... en} are already entailed to be distinct, you don't need to add anything. If the "array" elements must be distinct but are not yet entailed to be distinct, you can assert

```
(assert (distinct e1 ... en))
```

(This will probably be internally expanded to something quadratic in n.)
You can instead say that no 2 p variables can be true as once. Note that this is a weaker statement. To see this, suppose v = e1 = 1 and e2 = e3 = 0. Then p1 = true and p2 = p3 = false. The obvious encoding for these constraints is quadratic:

```
(assert (or (not pi) (not pj))) ; for all i < j
```

If you need a better encoding for this, try taking a look at how to encode "p1+ ... + pn <= 1" in [Translating Pseudo-Boolean Constraints into SAT](http://jsat.ewi.tudelft.nl/content/volume2/JSAT2_1_Een.pdf) section 5.3. I would only try this if the obvious encoding fails though.

Comment: I'll look into the pseudo-boolean constraints and into the trick that you provided. They look like good approaches to investigate. I'll assert that exactly one pn is true instead of distincting the inputs (which is semantically wrong).

Comment: I'm synthesizing programs computing a bitvec from another bitvec (like a bitcount program). Programs are a sequence of binary operators, each one applied to any of the previously computed results. I need to pick any of the available expressions for each input of the operator and I need to know which one it was so that I find out what program Z3 synthesized. Btw, I meanwhile tried all strategies that I proposed in the question. Arrays were the fastest, boolean the slowest. It seemed to me that the deeply nested ite chain hurt. Your assert trick allows me to circumvent that. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `(declare-datatypes () ((U e1 e2 ... en)))` do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make sure that each expression is quantifier free and uses only functions and predicates already present in the formula. If this is not the case then introduce a fresh propositional variable p_i for each index and assert ctx.MkIff(p_i, availableExprs[i]) to the solver.
When Z3 produces a model, use model.Eval(p_i) and check if the result is the expression "True".

Comment: MkIff is identical to MkEq, right? `availableExprs[i]` could have any type (not necessarily boolean). I don't get why I'd want to assert that the "index booleans" are equal to the switch values. Can you clarify?